# ¿como colocar la funcion leer mas a la descripcion corta de producto en woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

He usado este codigo en el archivo functions.php pero solo funciona si en la descripción hay un solo parrafo, cuando hay parrafos adicionales los ignora.

```js
/**  Truncate Short Description @ WooCommerce Single
 
 */

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'bbloomer_woocommerce_short_description_truncate_read_more' );
 
function bbloomer_woocommerce_short_description_truncate_read_more() { 
   wc_enqueue_js('
      var show_char = 100;
      var ellipses = "... ";
      var content = $(".woocommerce-product-details__short-description").html();
      if (content.length > show_char) {
         var a = content.substr(0, show_char);
         var b = content.substr(show_char - content.length);
         var html = a + "<span class=\'truncated\'>" + ellipses + "<a class=\'read-more\'>Read more</a></span><span class=\'truncated\' style=\'display:none\'>" + b + "</span>";
         $(".woocommerce-product-details__short-description").html(html);
      }
      $(".read-more").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(".woocommerce-product-details__short-description .truncated").toggle();
      });
   ');
}
```

[image: Imagen de como se ve en la pagina de producto]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes meter una linea de código dentro del texto y colocar este ejemplo que te pongo aquí, si funciona igual que el wordpress es colocar envés de párrafo código encriptado dentro del texto.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-5" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Leer mas</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>
```